# Ruby Grape: Custom validation error message

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, grape-api

How do you change the default error messages given by Grape on Validation Errors?

For Example -

```
params do
    requires :email, allow_blank: false
end
```

If I don't pass the `:email` in the API call, grape will give error message as `['email is missing', 'email is empty']` but I want to override the message as `['Oops! Email is required.']`

So, how can I override the default error messages for Grape default Validation Rules.

Comment: try to read gem documentation

Comment: I have read the docs a few times, but it doesn't say anything about Custom Error messages.

Answer (score 1):

```
format :json
subject.rescue_from Grape::Exceptions::ValidationErrors do |e|
  error!({ messages: e.full_messages.map { |msg| "Oops!" + msg }}, 400)
end
```

Update:

If you want to customize the complete message you can manually edit the grape locale file and override it in your application.

[Grape locale en.yml](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape/blob/master/lib/grape/locale/en.yml)

Comment: I don't want to just add "Oops" before the message, I want to change the message completely.

Comment: Grape does not have a message option to pass to the params block to override the default validation messages right now. I have updated the answer for you.

Comment: I guess then I might end up doing just that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the original answer is plain wrong:

https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape#custom-validation-messages

Which should work something like this for OP's example:

```rb
params do
    requires :email, allow_blank: { false, message: '' }, message 'Oops! Email is required.'
end
```

The tricky part is that OP is violating 2 validations but wants to have one message. Maybe the workaround above will work, though.

Comment: This feature was not available on Grape when the original answer was provided by me. The above custom validation feature which you have shown or pointing to was of course implemented by me to overcome this short comings in the Grape API.

Comment: Take a look at this pull request https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape/pull/1295

Comment: @Rubysmith sorry, did probably not have the timings in mind when writing my answer. Thank you for your work!